# Number of ways to divide exam papers to TAs

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If 2 distinct TAs have to mark papers of a class of 109s student, and they check 55 and 54 papers respectively, in how many ways can the papers be distributed?

My attempt: `(109C55) + (109C54)` (Letting TA1 choose 55 exams first or letting TA2 choose 54 exams first).

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once TA A has chosen their 55, the 54 exams that TA B will end up with is determined, so it is just ${109 \choose 55}$. Alternatively, you can think of it as ${109 \choose 55} {54 \choose 54}$ (TA A chooses their 55 and then TA B "chooses" their 54 from among the 54 that are still remaining), which is the same number, but this formula generalizes a bit better. Which one of them chooses papers first doesn't change the number of ways to do the assignments.

This is easier to see in a small setting, for example if there are two students and each TA grades one, then there are obviously two configurations but your logic would yield 4.